# How to customize hover text of box plot trace in plotly.js?

Tags: angular, plotly, hover, boxplot, plotly.js

I would like to create a box plot and **customize the hover text**. Creating the boxplot was successful. However, the goal is to have measurement title, min, q1, median, q3, max from top to bottom inside an overlay box ([example, ignore numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cs4u.png)), and not the default behavior. Here is a link to a minimal example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a5g2db?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I'm using angular-plotly and plotlyjs.

What I've tried:

- set hovertemplate variable to some text (seems not to work?)
- playing around with hoverinfo and hovertext ([see ref](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#box-hovertemplate))
- trying to use the hover event from angular-plotly, where I actually got the desired data, but I don't know how to access the "hover DOM element" to attach my string to (see stackblitz > app.component.ts > hoverTrigger())